# SimpleDateFormat not working when formatting this date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to format this date to output something like Mon Feb 12,2008

```
try {
  date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("02/12/2008").toString();
} catch (ParseException e) {
  Log.v(TAG,e.getMessage());
}
String dateParsed = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM/dd/yyyy").format(date);
```

I am getting an illegal argument exception.

Comment: Please post the error in its entirety and indicate the *offending* line in your code.

Comment: So we're assuming "date" is not a String type, right?

Comment: I just saw my mistake as pointed out by the answer below. I was storing the date object as a string then trying to format it.

Comment: I'm glad you've solved your question, but please take @PM77-1's suggestions to heart for your next question. If you ever have errors in your code that you're asking about, post the full error messages with your question, and indicate which lines are causing the errors. Also, you will want to format your posted code as nicely as possible (which I just tried to do for you above), so that we all can read and understand it well. Much luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appear to be trying to set a Date = to a String:

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("02/12/2008").toString();
```

and that will never work.

If the date variable is actually a String variable, then that won't work either, since you'll be trying to call `SimpleDateFormat#format(...)` with a String parameter, and it requires a Date object.

Instead be sure that the date variable is in fact a `Date` variable, parse the String into a Date object, assign it to date (and don't call `toString()` on it), and then format the date variable after you've got it.